# Problem with Scaling

Tags: bezier-curves, edit-mode

I am learning to make an alarm clock but the problem is my scaling is not happening like the one in the youtube video am learning from. My scaling was supposed to be like this [image] , but it's coming out like this, all selected lines r scaling together it seems [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **Proportional editing mode** enabled !

In this particular case you probably don't want that when scaling.

[image]

Just to add: the keyboard short key for toggling Proportional editing on and off is the **O** key.

Comment: Worked. Problem solved